# Replace placeholders in property file with VM argument passed (-D params) using spring 4

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc

I want to have a dynamic placeholders in my property file

My application.properties file

## properties

```
property.first=${some-value} (placeholder in property file )
```

I want to replace above placeholder (${some-value}) with the value passed via VM argument say , `-Dsome-value=12`.

Actually i can achieve it through @Value annotation in spring boot , but i am using spring 4 with xml configurations . Is there any solution by adding any xml configuration in ApplicationContext.xml file.(I dont want to change java code )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read your .properties file in a [Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) object and then replace the placeholders by the values passed via VM arguments:

```
public static boolean replaceVariables(Properties properties) {
        boolean changed = false;
        for (Entry<Object, Object> entry : properties.entrySet()) {
            if (entry.getValue() instanceof String) {
                String value = (String) entry.getValue();
                value = value.trim();
                if (value.startsWith("${") && value.endsWith("}")) {
                    value = System.getProperty(value.substring(2, value.length() - 1));
                    if (value == null)
                        entry.setValue("");
                    else
                        entry.setValue(value);
                    changed = true;
                }
            }
        }
        return changed;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks this one does that , but when i access same property from another class it is still giving me same older value